# Does Firefox (57.0.1) support setting from javascript a command shortcut key in a webextension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've created a little extension in the recent webextension format, it has a couple of commands defined as:

```
  "commands": {
    "mycommand1": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+K",
        "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+K",
        "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+K",
        "windows":"Ctrl+Shift+K"
      },
      "description": "do something 1"
    }
```

now I would like to give the ability to the users to customize these keyboard shortcuts, however when i do:

```
var getCommands = browser.commands.getAll();
getCommands.then(setCommandsSettings);

function setCommandsSettings(commands){
    commands.forEach(function(command) {
        if(command.name=="mycommand1"){
          command.shortcut="MacCtrl+Shift+L";
        }
      });
}
```

If I check the command.shortcut property I see that it has been changed to the new value, however the commands still gets involved only by pressing the old shortcut. Am I doing something wrong? Is it supported by FF changing the shortcut at runtime?

Comment: Doesn't appear so :( Really looks like it's only going to pull from the manifest. Makes sense so you can't hijack someone's keyboard? Not sure.

Comment: Might be, but user customization of keyboard shortcuts sounds a big and legit use case too. Seems there is some degree of hope for the future: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/commands-how-to-redefine-shorcuts/15984 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1303384

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems that it's not yet supported (as of Firefox 57.0.1) however there's a bug open for a enhancement allowing this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1303384